# Store literal bytes4 as string

Tags: solidity, contract-development, bytes

Does anyone have the 'somefunc' below to store bytes (specifically bytes4) as a string?  Ideally something to get method_s in the code below:

```
contract Test{
  bytes4 public method;
  string public method_s;

  function Test() {
    method = this.get_f.selector;
  }

  function makeString(){
   method_s = somefunc(method);
  }

}
```

So I need 
method = 0x0cb9ef7a
and method_s = "0x0cb9ef7a"

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will convert a bytes4 to an hexadecimal string

```
function toHexDigit(uint8 d) internal pure returns (bytes1) {
    if (0 <= d && d <= 9) {
        return bytes1(uint8(bytes1("0")) + d);
    } else if (10 <= uint8(d) && uint8(d) <= 15) {
        return bytes1(uint8(bytes1("a")) + d - 10);
    }
    revert();
}

function fromCode(bytes4 code) public pure returns (string memory) {
    bytes memory result = new bytes(10);
    result[0] = bytes1("0");
    result[1] = bytes1("x");
    for (uint i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        result[2 * i + 2] = toHexDigit(uint8(code[i]) / 16);
        result[2 * i + 3] = toHexDigit(uint8(code[i]) % 16);
    }
    return string(result);
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm.  I was working at it trying to use assembly, but this is a solid.  Thanks for the effort

Comment: It should not be hard to write assembly directly, but short string have a particular encoding than can be annoying, look at this article for the deailt of string & arrays storage https://medium.com/@hayeah/diving-into-the-ethereum-vm-the-hidden-costs-of-arrays-28e119f04a9b.

Answer (score 1):

adopted to 0.8+

```
  function toHexDigit(uint8 d) pure internal returns (bytes1) {
    if (0 <= d && d <= 9) {
      return bytes1(uint8(bytes1('0')) + d);
    } else if (10 <= uint8(d) && uint8(d) <= 15) {
      return bytes1(uint8(bytes1('a')) + d - 10);
    }
    revert();
  }

  function fromCode(bytes4 code) public pure returns (string memory) {
    bytes memory result = new bytes(10);
    result[0] = bytes1('0');
    result[1] = bytes1('x');
    for (uint i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
      result[2 * i + 2] = toHexDigit(uint8(code[i]) / 16);
      result[2 * i + 3] = toHexDigit(uint8(code[i]) % 16);
    }
    return string(result);
  }
```